# Eigen missing from the installation for OpenCV3

Tags: python, opencv, installation, opencv3.0

I have been trying to install Opencv3 using [this](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/15/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-osx/) installation guide.

I had trouble building `opencv_contrib` extras, can’t find `unsupported/Eigen`, in step 8 of the guide.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to solve it by using [this](http://www.alecjacobson.com/weblog/?tag=eigen) blog post.

You just have to run the following line of code:

`cmake -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib/modules -DEIGEN_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/include/eigen3/ ..`

Tweak the path `/usr/local/include/eigen3/` to make sure it leads to the `Homebrew` install location for `eigen3` in your computer.